# restricting items in cart and calculating

Tags: magento

I'm currently trying to create a 'Sample' functionality on my Magento site.

The samples are free but when there more than 5 in the cart, then the total needs to be $10.

I can add the 'sample' products to the cart programatically  that's no problem.

My main problem is:

Checking how many Sample products are in the cart (all have a value of $0)

If there are 5 or more, then the total needs to be $10+tax (or add this to the current total)

There cannot be more than 10 samples in the cart at one time(so no more than 10 $0 products)

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To loop through the items in your cart you can loop through

```
foreach (Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
    if ($item->getPrice() == 0) {
        //this item is a sample
    }
}
```

To prevent things from adding to the cart you can overwrite the `addProduct` method in `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Cart.php` to add your own custom logic to prevent products from being added to the cart when you don't want them. To make sure you are overriding correctly, you can learn more at http://alanstorm.com/magento_upgrade_rewrite_override

Comment: What about adding the $10 to the subtotal? Would I need to write an observer?

Comment: An Observer is a pattern for writing code, not necessary for actual placement of code. Place the code where it makes sense. I think you need, however to be setting the price of the Samples at `$10 / $numberOfSamples` or perhaps adding another item to the cart called "Sample Pack" which costs $10. That can be done whenever an item is added to the car to make sure that the cart is always in a valid state.